# Schedule batch file not renaming file to name specified using %date% and %time% variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, server, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

As part of a regular file upload process we run a .bat file via Windows Task Scheduler.  It opens WinSCPand runs it using a config file.

Then it cds to the file where the upload is stored, renames it, then moves it to the archive file.

If I run the program manually with a `pause` before the `exit`, it works fine.  Currently is just dumping the file from upload to the archive without renaming it with time and date appended.

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=CONFIG.txt

cd C:\SCHEDULEDQUERIES\PressGaney\Upload

ren *.csv CL6019_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%date:~-10,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~-4,4%.csv

move *.csv C:\SCHEDULEDQUERIES\PressGaney\archive

exit
```

Thanks.  Happy to give any further details that may be needed.

Comment: I would suggest you change, `%date:~3,2%` to `%date:~-7,2%` to maintain the same format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lack of further information, I'd suggest

```
ren *.csv "CL6019_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%date:~-10,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~-4,4%.csv"
```

should cure the problem. If not, `echo` this line and then `pause` the script.

Perhaps your `time` format - or the `time` format used by the by the user under which the job is being run by the task scheduler - is set to single-digit hours, which replaces the leading `0` in the time with a space, so the original `ren` function sees three arguments, not two.

Of course, f you try to debug this during normal working hours, after morning coffee at 10:00 or later, the time won't contain the space, so it seems to work with your tests.

Comment: it'll run again tomorrow at 0530  i added the " " and we can see if that works.  I will report back tomorrow morning.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the batch file to another one and redirect its complete output to a log file:

```
winscp_script.bat > c:\writable\path\winscp_script.log
```

Next day, inspect the log file for any errors.

---

In general, you should not rely on `%TIME%` and `%DATE%` variables, as their format is locale specific. The local account that runs your Windows Scheduler task can have a different locale than the one you use to test the batch file. Not only you get a wrong name, but if the resulting format includes spaces, it would completely break the `ren` command (as already suggested by @Magoo).

[WinSCP itself has a built-in feature for time formatting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_formatting_timestamp_batch_file), so you can do something like:

```
set TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=hhnnddmmyyyy

pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (
    `winscp.com /command "echo %%TIMESTAMP#%TIMESTAMP_FORMAT%%%" "exit"`
) do set TIMESTAMP=%%F
popd

echo %TIMESTAMP%
ren *.csv CL6019_%TIMESTAMP%.csv
```

Comment: thank you very very much.  i had not considered the impact of Local time on  my programs.  this one should never be an issue since it is just an archive running on a single server in the next room.  but in the future I'll definitely go by UTC.      I'll try out the timestamp feature on my next project [link](http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/08/07/why-not-to-use-server-local-time.html) <<a good explanation of of the issues for others  thanks!!!!

Comment: By "locale" I do not mean timezone (though that's indeed an issue too). I mean locale time format. The account you are using may have for example UK time format `dd/mm/yyyy`, while the Scheduler account may have US time format `mm/dd/yyyy` or yet another. Time format would differ too, between 12- and 24- hour systems.

Comment: ah i understand!